# xeCJK - CJK text colors for customized commands not changing as specified

Tags: fonts, color, fontspec, cjk, xecjk

I'm using the template [Deedy-Resume](https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume) to create my resume. English version works fine, however I'm not sure how to create a Chinese version properly. I used the package `xeCJK`. The fonts are rendered but their colors in each customized command don't change according to each `\color` specified. Instead they all just stick to the color I set in `\setCJKmainfont`.

The author of the template class defined a customized command as such: `\newcommand{\location}[1]{\color{headings}\raggedright\fontspec{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont {#1\\} \normalfont}`. I guess the `\color` here only works for English texts. Even if I specified `\color` explicitly for each command in my `.tex` file, there's no effect.

Is there a way to set CJK text colors for customized commands to be different than that set in `\setCJKmainfont` in xeCJK? Or do I have to resort to some other means?

Thank you.

(The class file for the template I'm using can be found at https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume/blob/master/OpenFonts/deedy-resume-openfont.cls)

Comment: An easy way may be to define a command for CJK string:
`\newcommand{\locationcjk}[1]{`
`\color{headings}\raggedright\fontspec{Your-CJKfontName}`
`\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont {#1\\} \normalfont}`,
where `Your-CJKfontName` should be an actual font name
which you have.

Comment: Try remove colors from `\setCJKmainfont` and use `\color{some}\rmfamily` instead of `rmfamily`.